# NEAR API with Python

Tags: nearprotocol

A community member would like to utilise Python to integrate aspects of their application with NEAR. Would it be possible to build an application on NEAR using Python? Can the NEAR API be used with Python?

Comment: We have a python library, but it is right now part of NearCore: 
https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/pull/2437/files#diff-1985e75e1a70443b9d1b41cd3787065b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With NEAR you build on 2 fronts:

1. "Inside": **Contracts** (to write code that runs on-chain and changes state in the system)
2. "Outside": **API** (to create dApps that communicate with NEAR)

#### Contracts

We currently support two languages:

- Rust ([`near-sdk-rs`](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs))
- and AssemblyScript [(`near-sdk-as`](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-as))

You can find more examples of contracts written in both of these languages in our [NEAR Examples GitHub org](https://github.com/near-examples), many of which are running live on [near.dev](http://near.dev/)

In the future we will support any language that we (or our community) decides to enable from a [pretty long list](https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs)  where “enable” means building out the sdk like `near-sdk-rs` and `near-sdk-as` linked above.

#### API

We currently have a [JSON RPC API](https://docs.near.org/docs/interaction/rpc) that you can use from any language ([including Python](https://pypi.org/project/json-rpc/)) as well as a convenient wrapper for JavaScript developers called [near-api-js](https://github.com/near/near-api-js).  Again, we (or our community) can decide to build more convenient wrappers for any other language we want to support, including Go, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, etc

As a side note, if someone in the community is interested in Python specifically, there’s a ton of it currently being used to do things like run tests ([nearcore pytest](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/tree/master/pytest/)), manage builds ([nearcore scripts](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/tree/master/scripts)) and deploy nodes ([nearup](https://github.com/near/nearup)) as well as simulate some of the on-chain stuff like the Runtime

Answer (score 1):

I use **py-near**

https://pypi.org/project/py-near/

- built-in transactions with FT
- fully asynchronous library
- [good documentation](https://py-near.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- built-in transfers NEAR/Ft by SMS
- multiple RPC node support