# NEAR blockchain API implementation for ruby

Tags: nearprotocol

I am wondering if NEAR blockchain API implementation exists for ruby.

I can find API for js and a little bit for python, but not for ruby.

Answer (score 0):

we don't have anything at this point for the ruby community but would be happy to fund a grant to support this work if you are interested and able to deliver it

**apply for a grant here: [near.university / teach](https://near.university/teach)**

you can start here to explore the API
https://docs.near.org/docs/api/overview

and investigate the JS, Python and Rust API wrappers for inspiration

- JS: https://github.com/near/near-api-js
- Python: https://pypi.org/project/json-rpc/
- Rust: https://github.com/near/near-jsonrpc-client-rs

and here's a little more context about building on NEAR that may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953470/2836874